# Explanation for spark read json for parallel calls

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Due to some reasons it is needed to call spark in the following way:

```
val session: SparkSession = ...

mylist.grouped(10).foreach(batch =>
  session.read
    .option("basePath", myBasepath)
    .json(batch.map(p => /* calc path here*/)
```

This works but what if I run foreach in parallel and there will be multiple calls session.read same time? I understand that spark
driver will create multiple tasks but is it safe to create them? I mean will I get OutOfMemoryException or other errors
due to large number of tasks or not? Or spark is able to keep some tasks in pending state until other processed and
custer resources become available?

Comment: Do not downvote without comments! :-)

Comment: Yes, spark is able to keep tasks in pending state until others are processed and cluster resources become available. https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/22/understanding-your-spark-application-through-visualization.html
But, with too many resources available :) (=too many task slots to execute tasks in parallel) and tasks themselves being short, you run the risk of driver's ListenerBus starting to drop events (see spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.capacity), and BlockManager loosing track of block locations/status and requiring executors to confirm them, among other side-effects.